# Using ajax with Hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I've created a bookmark page that retrieves links from a database and displays it. I'm able to log in, add new links & delete them. However, when I delete an entry it displays *delete.php* instead of loading the page onto itself (the query does work).

I've most likely over-complicated my code at this point and am probably overlooking something simple, as I've used a lot of JavaScript for other elements of the page.

The entries are added dynamically so this part of the HTML is being appended:

```
<h2>
    <a href="delete.php?URL='+url+'">[x]</a>
</h2>
<a href="'+url+'" target="iFrame" class="linkURL">
    <div class="bookmark">
        <h3 style="float: left;">'+title+'</h3>
        <br />
        <p>'+desc+'</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
//  DELETE FUNCTION
$("h2 a").click(function() {
    return false;
    var action = $(this).attr('href');
    var form_data = {
        URL: $("#linkURL").attr('href'),
        is_ajax: 1
    }; // form_data
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response){
            if(response == 'success') {
                alert('Successful delete!');
            } else { // if
                alert('Delete failed.');
            } // else
        } // function(response)
    }); // ajax
    return false;
}); // h2
```

The page is located here: http://samaradionne.com/links6/ if it is easier to view the whole thing.

Comment: Try changing this `$("h2").click(function(e) { ` to this `$("h2 a").click(function(e) { `. That way your prevent default, will prevent the link from doing the normal action of following the `href`.

Comment: @tw16 Added the h2 a. Also I would have changed the formatting of that line however that's how I need to have it in the function to append it.

Comment: I changed the formatting so it was easier for others to read. It can remain how it is in your function. Did it make any difference targeting the `a` instead of the `h2`?

Comment: I understand, but no, it still reloaded the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my links were dynamically generated, my .h2 a click was attaching itself to something that wasn't there yet. I added an event trigger to my append function that calls to my delete function.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You are using both an anchor tag `a` and a click event.  You are getting the actual delete.php page because when you click on the anchor tag it works just like any regular link.  You have no where in your code something that says "hey, don't actually follow this link like normal".

To *not* follow the link, you need

```
<a href="yoururl" onclick="return false;">[x]</a>
```

Furthermore, you attached your jQuery click event to the `h2`, which is not bad in of itself, just confusing as the intent is to actually click the link.  In that case, you need:

```
$("h2 a").click(function(){});
```

Lastly, to bring this all together, you could do the following:

```
 $("h2 a").click(function(){
     // your normal logic

     return false; // don't follow link
 });
```

And then you don't have to have the `onclick` inside the anchor tag.

Comment: Wouldn't I be doing that with e.preventDefault(); ?

Comment: @Phawkes e.preventDefault() would work as well.  I don't recall browser compatabilities off the top of my head, but if it were me I would do `e.preventDefault(); return false;`

Comment: I have return false; already in the function or is how far down it is effecting it? Added the h2 a though.

Comment: @Phawkes you have `return false`, but your click event is on the h2.  The anchor tag doesn't hear that message at all.  That's why you should attach the event to the `a` instead of the `h2`

Comment: I've added the return false here `$("h2 a").click(function() { 
        return false;` but the page is still sending it, however if I add the `onclick="return false;"` to the actual link, that is stopping the reload.

Comment: Do you see any other glaring reason why it would not be working?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you.  Works fine for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/rb98q/1/.  Make sure your JS is execution after domReady, as it depends on the nodes to exist in order to attach the events.